# PWA Hosted on firebase behaves diffrenly depending on how it's accessed

Tags: android, firebase, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I am developing a PWA and hosting it on Firebase. The issue is, when deployed to Firebase, the application behaves diffrently, depending on how it's being accessed.

Diffrent ways i'm accessing it and their outcome:

1. From Chrome browser on Windows. Behaves as expected, showing all pages correctly.
2. From Chrome browser on Android. Behaves as expected, except for one page not loading content from database. (This data is loading from another page).
3. From Chrome browser on Android, with the application installed, and opening the installed application from Chrome's three dots and then "Open application". Behaves as example 2, just running as an application (without url at the top etc.).
4. From homescreen icon on Android device. Shows the splash screen and then shows the json contents of the manifest file?.

This is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name": "Smart Sockets",
    "short_name": "SmartSockets",
    "start_url": "./index.html",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#BBDEFB",
    "theme_color": "#BBDEFB",
    "orientation": "portrait-primary",
    "icons": [{
            "src": "/img/icons/Artboard-72.jpg",
            "type": "image/png",
            "sizes": "72x72"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my firebase.json file.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried setting "start_ul" to "/", "", "./index.html", same results.
And i've tried clearing caching in all the diffrent scenarios, and it does'nt make a diffrence.

What could be the cause of these diffrent behavious?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After struggling a lot, I tried with a different mobile device and it worked. I deleted all of the cookies and stored data for the site, uninstalled the PWA, and tried again and it worked.